# Why isn't Document Viewer 2.32.0 using subpixel rendering?

Tags: pdf

Adobe Reader:

[image]

Document Viewer:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue that the Evince Document Viewer does not support subpixel rendering.

Do a Google search for `evince subpixel rendering`.

The explanation

```
Well, actually the problem is not that patches are not good enough,
the problem is that it's not possible to enable subpixel-hinted
rendering without breaking transparencies. For subpixel-hinted
rendering to work we would need to first fill the surface in white and
then call poppler_page_render to render the page, but PDF blend modes
need an initially transparent surface to work. We consider blend modes
more important than subpixel-hinted rendering of fonts.
```

Source: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/evince-list/2010-October/msg00022.html

There are patches to use to enable subpixel rendering. It is possible to apply them, even if you are not a programmer.

In any case, subscribe to the bug report at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/poppler/+bug/80921